# Rankx not working because context changed

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a dataset named "CollectionData". I will introduce you the columns in the table and the first 5 rows in these columns.

[image]

Toplam Tahsilat = SUM(CollectionData[CollectionTRY])

Toplam Anapara = SUM(CollectionData[CurrentUPB])

What I want to do is I split the "Toplam Tahsilat" and "Toplam Anapara" fields into each other. I sorted them by "EkipName" and "CollectionSourceName" columns, from largest to smallest. No problems so far. I am sharing the Measure below.

```
SIRALAMA =

IF(
OR(
HASONEFILTER(CollectionData[EkipName]),
HASONEFILTER(CollectionData[CollectionSourceGroup])
),
RANKX(
ALL(CollectionData[EkipName],CollectionData[CollectionSourceGroup]),
DIVIDE([Toplam Tahsilat], [Toplam Anapara], 0)
)
)
```

[image]

It should not be forgotten that there was also a "Date" field in Raw Data, but I removed the "Date" field in the table. So I changed the Context and sorted accordingly.

But what I want to do is I want to show the value of "EkipName" as "Card" of the row with the largest order. I wrote the following DAX for this, but it doesn't work. Because the Context is different.

```
ForCard =
IF (
    [SIRALAMA] = 1,
    MAXX ( FILTER ( CollectionData , [SIRALAMA] = 1 ), CollectionData[EkipName] )
)
```

Can anyone help? Thanks.